# Print Line if output is greater than a certain number

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I want to print a line of text into a `label` if the output is past a certain number (in this case `6`). I was thinking of using an `if-else` statement, but I can't quite figure it out.

Any tips?

Comment: `if output > 6 { label.text = "\(output)" }`

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting a bad instruction error. 
I have my code as:
if output > 6 {label.text = "max 6 mg"

Comment: Is your label set up as an `@IBOutlet`?  Make sure it is connected to the label in your storyboard.  The little circle next to the label on the left should be filled in.

Comment: Ah!!! I I forgot to link it. Thanks!! If you want "answer" the question Ill mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would set the label text to the `output` value if that value is larger than `6`:

```
if output > 6 {
    label.text = "\(output)"
}
```

From the comments:

> I tried that but I keep getting a bad instruction error. I have my
>   code as:
>
> ```
> if output > 6 {
>     label.text = "max 6 mg"
> }
> ```

This usually happens when you have an `IBOutlet` that isn't hooked up.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

Make sure the little circle next to the `@IBOutlet` on the left is filled in.  If it is hollow, drag from the middle of the circle to the label in your Storyboard.